# How to see graphical view of Android Project?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Eclipse and I want to see the graphical view of Android project. I want to see the graphical view of the project so I can add things to it. Please help me. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the layout (inside `res/layouts`) you want to edit, and once it's open, if it shows the XML version, click the tab below the file view that stands by `Graphical Layout`